# Wait until ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is finished

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, delay, prompt

I'm converting my JavaScript code to ASP.NET code, but I ran into an issue.
I still use JS code to show the user a prompt window (Using JS code in code behind).

The JS code gets executed and the input of the user gets saved in a hiddenfield.
After the code I read the value from the hiddenfield and save that in a string to use later.

The problem is that the code for reading the hiddenfield value gets executed before the JS code has been executed, which results in an empty string.

How can I let my code what until the JS code has been completely executed?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "prompt", "var value = prompt('Enter your password here.'); storeinput(value);", true);
    string code = hidValue.Value;
    Debug.WriteLine("Password: " + code);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can not do this, for this sample you can use ajax to call server side method, after js code running finished... RegisterStartupScript just register js code to page and dos not granity to execute and wait to finished work

Comment: Oh, that's annoying. Could you point me to an example that uses JS and code behind using AJAX? I'm not very familiar with AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put ScriptManager in asp.net page Like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" EnablePageMethods="true"
    runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
```

create method in page and decorate [WebMethod] attribute

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GetPasswordFromClient(string password) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Password: " + password);
}
```

and write this code in javascript :

```
function OnSucceeded_SendPasswordToServer(result, userContext, methodName) {

}

function OnFailed_SendPasswordToServer(error, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(error);
}

function SendPasswordToServer(string password) {
    PageMethods.GetPasswordFromClient(password, OnSucceeded_SendPasswordToServer, OnFailed_SendPasswordToServer); 
}
```

and now you can use register script or in your page use :

```
var value = prompt('Enter your password here.'); 
SendPasswordToServer(value);
```